# Java Threading in producer consumer pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I have a code using Producer and Consumer pattern . Where producer produces some data objects puts them in a Blocking Queue , The consumer consumes from the queue process the data objects and sends it to another class

Producer --> Blocking Queue(Data Object) <-- Consumer --> Parser --> other application

Now the rate at which the producer produces can vary which means the data object enqueued can vary.

TO process all the data Object from the queue the consumer needs to run in threads.

Now my requirement is where there is huge amount of data objects enqueued I am increasing consumer threads to a predefined number so that the dataobjects are processed in time , but when there is less amount of data queue/ the data in the queue is reduced I want to reduce the threads also.

In short I want to vary the number of threads based on the size of queue. What is the best possible way I can achieve this.

Comment: What did you find out in your research? What options did you already try out? With what results? Did you have problems with the implementation (in that case, post specific questions about your implementation) or did the result not satisfy you?

Comment: Consider using a `java.util.concurrentThreadPoolExecutor` instead of using an explicitly created queue and explicitly created threads.  `ThreadPoolExecutor` automatically adjusts the number of worker threads between a given `corePoolSize` and a given `maximumPoolSize`.

Comment: Worked Using java.util.concurrentThreadPoolExecutor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked Using java.util.concurrentThreadPoolExecutor